# Query on 3 different tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've these 3 tables:

**___Invoices:**

```
|--------|---------------|
| INV_Id | IVC_BookingId |
|--------|---------------|
| 10     | 31            |
|--------|---------------|
```

**___Bookings:**

```
|--------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_GuestId | BOO_CompanyId | BOO_BillingId |
|--------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
| 10     | 89            90            | 0             |
|--------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
```

**___Kardex:**

```
|--------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| KDX_Id | KDX_Type | KDX_Name    | KDX_Company |
|--------|----------|-------------|-------------|
| 89     | guest    | Frank       |             |
| 90     | company  |             | Google      |
|--------|----------|-------------|-------------|
```

I would like to find for an Invoice the linked card user.

For example, for `INV_Id = 10`, it should return me:

```
|--------|-------|---------|---------|
| INV_Id | guest | company | billing |
|--------|-------|---------|---------|
| 10     | Frank | Google  | 0       |
|--------|-------|---------|---------|
```

`billing` is actually empty because I do not have any existing like between my invoice and booking and kardex.

So my try is the following:

```
SELECT IVC_Id, IVC_BookingId, IFNULL(BOO_GuestId, 0) AS BOO_GuestId, IFNULL(BOO_CompanyId, 0) AS BOO_CompanyId, IFNULL(BOO_BillingId, 0) AS BOO_BillingId, KDX_Name, KDX_Company 
FROM ___Invoices 
JOIN ___Bookings
ON ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___Invoices.IVC_BookingId
LEFT JOIN ___Kardex
ON ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_BillingId
WHERE IVC_Id='10'
```

I've no error but I can get the name or company from the `___Kardex` table.

Do you know why please ?

Here the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/211d01/1

Thanks.

Comment: How these tables are related to each other? Can you tell us what are the foreign keys?

Comment: Hello @NimeshkaSrimal. Thanks for your interest. `___Bookings` table in link with `___Invoices` with `BOO_Id` and `IVC_BookingId`. `___Kardex` table in link with `___Bookings` with `KDX_Id` and `BOO_GuestId` or `BOO_CompanyId` or `BOO_BillingId`.

Comment: Yeah, check if this works? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/211d01/31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about your relationships or foreign keys. But from what you have given, I think this would do. Might need slight modifications, but I guess you will get the idea.

```
SELECT ___Invoices.IVC_Id, k1.KDX_Name as guest, k2.KDX_Company as company
FROM ___Invoices 
JOIN ___Bookings
ON ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___Invoices.IVC_BookingId
LEFT JOIN ___Kardex k1 ON ___Bookings.BOO_GuestId = k1.KDX_Id
LEFT JOIN ___Kardex k2 ON ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId = k2.KDX_Id
WHERE ___Invoices.IVC_Id='10'
```

Please check this and let me know if it's what you wanted.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/211d01/31

Feel free to ask if you have any doubts. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello. It's woking. Last question. If my `___Kardex` table contains more informations than `KDX_Name` or `KDX_Company`, like the address `KDX_Country` how I can concatenate this information to have `KDX_Name (KDX_Country)` for example ? Thanks.

Comment: @pocpoc could you please update the fiddle and add the data you wish then I can have a look. I'm going out, will be back in an hour.

Comment: How just found: `CONCAT(k1.KDX_Name,' ',k1. KDX_Country)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining to __Kardex on a BillingID of 0.

0 Does not equal 89 or 90

```
Your code


LEFT JOIN ___Kardex
ON ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_BillingId
```

Here is how I solved:  I joined to the same table twice with a different join criteria each time.  And then created a new alias for that join:

```
CREATE TABLE `inv` (`INV_ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `IVC_BookingID` 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `bookings` (`BOO_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `BOO_guestid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `BOO_CompanyID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `BOO_BillingID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `kardex` (`KDX_ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `KDX_TYPE` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `KDX_NAME` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `KDX_COMPANY` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO `inv` (INV_ID,IVC_BookingID) SELECT '10','31';
INSERT INTO `bookings` (BOO_id,BOO_guestid,BOO_CompanyID,BOO_BillingID) SELECT '10','89','90','0';
INSERT INTO `kardex` (KDX_ID,KDX_TYPE,KDX_NAME,KDX_COMPANY) SELECT '89','guest','Frank','';
INSERT INTO `kardex` (KDX_ID,KDX_TYPE,KDX_NAME,KDX_COMPANY) SELECT '90','company','','Google';

SELECT a.INV_ID, c.kdx_name, d.kdx_company FROM inv a 
INNER JOIN bookings b ON b.boo_id=a.INV_ID
INNER JOIN kardex c ON c.kdx_id=b.boo_guestid
INNER JOIN kardex d ON d.kdx_id=b.BOO_CompanyID
WHERE INV_ID='10';
```

RESULT

```
INV_ID  kdx_name    kdx_company
10       Frank      Google
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your second JOIN query:

```
LEFT JOIN ___Kardex
ON ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_BillingId
```

It should be

```
LEFT JOIN ___Kardex
ON ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/211d01/7

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT IVC_Id, 
(SELECT KDX_Name FROM ___Kardex WHERE KDX_Id= ___Bookings.BOO_GuestId) AS guest,
(SELECT KDX_Company FROM ___Kardex WHERE KDX_Id= ___Bookings.BOO_CompanyId) AS company,
___Bookings.BOO_BillingId as billing
FROM ___Invoices 
JOIN ___Bookings
ON ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___Invoices.IVC_BookingId
WHERE IVC_Id='10'
```

It probably not the most optimal solution if your concern is performance, but in you schema design you should not have one table handling more then one type of information, this makes it difficult to write any legit joins.